# javascript function always returning true while change to textbox

Tags: javascript

```
 function CheckLength(currentValue)
{
    var IsValid = true;
    if(currentValue>24)
    {
        alert("you can't enter more than 24 hours.");
        IsValid= false;
        //alert(IsValid);
    }
    else
    {
        return IsValid;

    }

}
function getHours(recordid,rowid,TsrDetailsId,effort) {
    debugger;
    var value= CheckLength(1);
    alert(value);

<input id="@("effort_" + items.RecordId+"_"+i)" type="text" title="@Model.TsCommentsLst[items.RecordId][i]" onkeyup=" return CheckLength(this.value);" style="width:60px" class="effortinput" onchange="getHours(@items.RecordId,@i,@items.TsrDetailsId,this.value)"  value="@Model.EffortList[items.RecordId][i]" />
```

**this is my function while returning it is giving correct one . if i call into another function it is always returning true. that is gethours function.in that gethours function it is always returning true. **

Comment: In getHours() you call it with a hard-coded value of 1, so yes, that will always return true. Also, shouldn't the function return true or false? Currently it returns true or undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was that the code was only returning a value if is was valid. Also inputs always return a string in `this.value` so we need to use the `parseInt` function.

```
function CheckLength(currentValue) {
  currentValue = parseInt(currentValue);
  var IsValid = true;
  if (currentValue >= 24) {
    alert("You can't enter more than 24 hours.");
    IsValid = false;
  }
  return IsValid;
}
```

Comment: The alert message will be misleading when `currentValue` is empty string.

Comment: @th1rdey3 The function could be inversed so that the default value could be false and the if statement where to change that. I'll update my answer when I have time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the actual input rather than it's length. Instead, use

```
if(currentValue.length > 24){
        alert("you can't enter more than 24 hours.");
        IsValid= false;
        //alert(IsValid);
}
```

Comment: Did you read the message in the alert? Pretty sure OP wants to test the actual value, not the length.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **parseInt** function if comparing two numbers..

```
if (parseInt(currentValue) > 24)
```

Comment: *"you should use parseInt function if comparing two numbers"* - unless the numbers are not integers. In any case, if you compare a string to a number with `>` the string gets coerced to a number.

Comment: [@nnnnnn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545832/javascript-function-always-returning-true-while-change-to-textbox/35545938#comment58780466_35545895) Really? I never knew that. Does that work is all browsers?

Comment: @BitByte - It should work in all browsers, if they implement what the ECMAScript spec says. Though if the string can't be converted to a number the result will be `false`. Best to validate input prior to comparison...

Answer (score 0):

You can even declare a variable and assign the value of the input to that variable and check if the variable is greater than 24.

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" size="20" id="abc"><!--giving an id-->
<script>
var a=document.getElementById('abc').value;
if (a>24){
    alert("The field cannot contain more than 5 characters!")
    return false
} else {
    return true
}
</script>
```